# PHP MySQL JSON custom output

Tags: php, mysql, json

i retrieve and print data from MySQL database in `json` method:

```
$ret = array();

$fileName = Access::FetchDB("SELECT name FROM tags");
    $ret[]= $fileName;
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Now output is:

```
[[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]]
```

But i need to This output:

```
["test1","test2","test3"]
```

How do i print this?

Comment: Just loop over `$fileName` and put the values into `$ret`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]]
```

is like having this

```
array(array(array('name' => 'test1'), array('name' => 'test2'), array('name' => 'test3')));
```

First, do **not** do this:

```
$ret[]= $fileName;
```

And keep only `$fileName` which should be something like this:

```
array(array('name' => 'test1'), array('name' => 'test2'), array('name' => 'test3'));
```

The better would even be to have `array('test1', 'test2', 'test3')` and encode it without array_values(). You could do it in php side:

```
$ret = array();
$fileName = Access::FetchDB("SELECT name FROM tags");

foreach($fileName as $key => $value)
   $ret[] = $value['name'];

echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: i tested but not worked for me! i see `[[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]]` output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
$ret = array();

$fileNames = Access::FetchDB("SELECT name FROM tags");
$ret = array_values($fileNames);
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. I answered something similar at first,   see my answer to understand why

Comment: I didn't notice the array in array, only the key value pairs. Sorry my fault.